# Access a certain array inside a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I want to have multiple ASCII art figures which I want to store inside different arrays.

I learned about methods in Java that they are used for splitting code into smaller parts. Therefore, my idea is to put the art into individual arrays inside a method, so it's tidy.

Is there a way to do so?
I made an example code to show how I imagine this.

My Google search about how to access a certain array inside a method didn't give me anything I can use.
I apologize if there already is a thread about this topic.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(divArr(arr2[1])); // expected output 20
    }

    public static void divArr() {
        int arr1[] {1, 2, 3};
        int arr2[] {10, 20, 30};
    }
}
```

Comment: The function needs to return stuff. Please follow a few java tutorials for a few weeks.

Comment: Thank you luk2302, I know about return value methods. The thing is I want to access these arrays on different events. I want to make it like a story, at the beginning the first ASCII art should be shown, next the second art, then the fifth, then third. How do I do this?

Comment: By calling it multiple times and returning different stuff each time. Either based on a parameter "iteration" or by having mutable state / a field called "iteration" that is updated and checked within the method.

Comment: I see, thank you luk2302

Comment: @KabraxisLuvos peoples don't like your question because its look like you haven't learned java and just began coding. which is ok, but its hard to ask a question and write an answer without a common language. sadly its too common that a beginner question get downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the idea of functions.
functions are actions, they accept parameters, calculate stuff and return a value.
for example this is a function that returns the average of 3 numbers:

```
public static int avarage(int a, int b, int c) {
    int sum = a + b + c;
    int result = sum / 3;
    return result;
}
```

You probably found information about javascript's dictionary, which have different syntax from java's function, although both of them have `{` and `}`

You can use the following approach:

```
public static class Main {
    public static int[] arr1 = {1,2,3};
    public static int[] arr2 = {10,20,30};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(arr2[1]);
    }
}
```

in this code, `arr1` and `arr2` are static variables.

You can also use a [Map](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/map.html#:%7E:text=The%20Java%20Map%20interface%2C%20java.&text=Map%20%2C%20represents%20a%20mapping%20between,value%20using%20just%20the%20key.) or a [Class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classes-objects-java/) instead

EDIT:

another approach will be to use 2 dimensional array:

```
public static class Main {
    public static int[][] frame1 = {
                                     {1,2,3},
                                     {10,20,30}
                                   };
    public static int[][] frame2 = {
                                     {4,5,6},
                                     {40,50,60}
                                   };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(frame1[1][1]);
    }
}
```